# Копирование из shared_ptr в unique_ptr

Tags: c++, алгоритм, классы, smart-pointer

Добрый вечер.

Сразу к теме: есть контейнер `map<int, unique_ptr<MySet>> mymap;` (MySet - пользовательский тип). Есть другой контейнер: `forward_list<shared_ptr<MySet>> myset;`

Вопрос: как из **forward_list** копировать элементы в **map** (из shared_ptr в unique_ptr)?

Comment: А смысл такого копирования? Если у вас во втором контейнере `unique_ptr`, то это должен быть единственный указатель на объект, а значит, `shared_ptr` на него быть не должно. Вы что-то делаете серьёзно неправильно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как я понимаю, объект класса `std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<MySet>>` должен быть владельцем указателей на объекты MySet, а потому при копировании нужно создавать копии объектов, хранящихся в `std::forward_list<std::shared_ptr<MySet>>`

Для этих целей можно использовать либо обычный цикл, либо стандартные алгоритмы, как, например, `std::transform`.

Ниже приведена демонстрационная программа, которая показывает, как можно использовать алгоритм `std::transform` для копирования элементов из одного контейнера в другой. Для наглядности в вызовы конструкторов и деструкторов класса, используемого в качестве базового элемента, я включил вывод на консоль.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <forward_list>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <utility>

struct A
{
    A() { std::cout << "A::A()" << std::endl; }
    A( const A & ) { std::cout << "A::A( const A & )" << std::endl; }
    ~A() { std::cout << "A::~A" << std::endl; }
    A & operator =( const A & ) 
    { 
        std::cout << "A::operator =( const A & )" << std::endl; 
        return *this;
    }
};

int main() 
{
    std::forward_list<std::shared_ptr<A>> lst;
    lst.push_front( std::shared_ptr<A>( new A ) );

    std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<A>> m;

    std::transform( lst.begin(), lst.end(), std::inserter( m, m.end() ),
                    []( auto p ) 
                    { 
                        return std::make_pair( 1, std::unique_ptr<A>( new A( *p.get() ) ) ); 
                    } );


    return 0;
}
```

Вывод на консоль будет:

```
A::A()
A::A( const A & )
A::~A
A::~A
```